# How does alcohol interact with sympathomimetics to affect the cardiovascular system?

Tags: pathology, pharmacology, cardiology, pathophysiology, alcohol

There is a fair amount of information on the cardiovascular effects of alcohol, and of sympathomimetics. How do they work? And how do their mechanisms interact?

We know that similar pathologies result from each. With alcoholics often experiencing mild left ventricular hypertrophy, mild diastolic dysfunction which preceeds systolic dysfunction, resistant hypertension; and a dilated cardiomyopathy - sympathomimetics leading to cardiomegaly, sinus tachycardia, left ventricular hypertrophy, and dilated cardiomyopathy #1.

An article notes that "alcohol competes with amphetamine for the metabolizing enzymes in the liver, therefore enhancing the bioavailability of amphetamine" #2. ***Are any effects of alcohol mediated by sympathomimetics/catecholamines, and if so which? Et vice versa.***

[1] Chemical Cardiomyopathies: The Negative Effects of Medications and Nonprescribed Drugs on the Heart https://bit.ly/2AMU6eM

[2] Myocardial Infarction Associated with Adderall XR and Alcohol Use in a Young Man https://bit.ly/2SV4wQD

[3] Cardioprotection by regular ethanol consumption: potential mechanisms and clinical application https://bit.ly/2RRVVAQ

[4] De Musset's sign https://bit.ly/2HljluG